# 3D modeling using camera

Tags: c++, c, 3d, camera

I'm looking for a sample code.

It's 3D modeling using camera.

like this: http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~qp202/my_papers/BMVC09/

Hopefully, I want to use c or c++.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that, since it's a 2009 research paper, you're not going to have much luck finding libraries or code. You should read the paper and try to reconstruct the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Don't we all! 
That is the joy of doing R'n'D (mostly D) based on academic research! 
On the other hand, you could try contacting the people who did that and discuss possibility of partnership (licensing the source files).

Answer (score 2):

You could try contacting the author of the paper to see if he's willing to release his source code to you.  It looks like he used [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) (for the Delauny Tetrahedralisation) so if you go that route, you'll need to get a copy of that.

Answer (score 2):

[openCv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is probably the easiest place to start.

There are a few chapters about creatign scenes from stereo pairs (which is a bit easier)  in the [opencv book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130) otherwise 3d models from image understanding is still possible - but a lot harder mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for computer vision functionality and [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) for 3D graphics. Both are widely used APIs with plenty of online documentation and examples, both official and third-party.